# bash script to eference value of $GECOS from /etc/passwd with awk or sed to extract first and last name

Tags: bash, nis, freeipa

Red Hat [has a sample script](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/migrating-from-nis) to migrate users from NIS to FreeIPA. `nis-user.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $1 is the NIS domain, $2 is the NIS master server
ypcat -d $1 -h $2 passwd > /dev/shm/nis-map.passwd 2>&1

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat /dev/shm/nis-map.passwd) ; do
    IFS=' '
    username=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d:)
    # Not collecting encrypted password because we need cleartext password
    # to create kerberos key
    uid=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d:)
    gid=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d:)
    gecos=$(echo $line | cut -f5 -d:)
    homedir=$(echo $line | cut -f6 -d:)
    shell=$(echo $line | cut -f7 -d:)

    # Now create this entry
    echo passw0rd1 | ipa user-add $username --first=NIS --last=USER \
         --password --gidnumber=$gid --uid=$uid --gecos='$gecos' --homedir=$homedir \
         --shell=$shell
    ipa user-show $username
done
```

This just sets the First name to NIS and last name to USER. Our `/etc/passwd` files has users that look like the following:

```
juser:x:4841:200:Jane Q. User:/home/juser:/bin/tcsh
kuser:x:5761:200:User, K.:/home/kuser:/bin/bash
```

So that of course complicates things. I got a suggestion that the following could extract the first and last names, and if they were reversed and comma separated (like kuser) it would catch most the names.

```
first=$(echo $gecos | sed -e 's/\(.*\), \(.*$\)/\2 \1/' | awk '{print $1}'
last=$(echo $gecos | sed -e 's/\(.*\), \(.*$\)/\2 \1/' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

How can I use `$first` and `$last`?

To test I tried to pipe the results of the `$gecos` variable to `awk`:

```
first=$(echo $line | cut -f5 -d: | awk '{print $1}':)

awk: cmd. line:1: {print $1}:
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
```

Same error is I try adding just the following line (after the `gecos=` line):

```
first=$(echo $gecos | awk '{print $1}':)
```

EDIT: ahhh the colon placement did me in. This works:

```
first=$(echo $gecos | sed -e 's/\(.*\), \(.*$\)/\2 \1/' | awk '{print $1}')
last=$(echo $gecos | sed -e 's/\(.*\), \(.*$\)/\2 \1/' | awk '{print $NF}')
```

So now on to the next part...

And then I want to take [this suggestion](https://freeipa-users.redhat.narkive.com/vTJsopZ5/problem-migrating-passwords-fro-nis-to-idm#post9), to import the passwords that use the CRYPT hash as demonstrated:

```
userpassword='{CRYPT}$6$blahblah$moregibberish' testuser
```

I followed Rob C's previous tips from [here](https://freeipa-users.redhat.narkive.com/vTJsopZ5/problem-migrating-passwords-fro-nis-to-idm#post10https://freeipa-users.redhat.narkive.com/vTJsopZ5/problem-migrating-passwords-fro-nis-to-idm#post10) and [here](https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2013-April/msg00058.html).

Not sure it matters but in  `/etc/libuser.conf`, `crypt_style = sha512`

In the script I added:

```
password1=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d:)
```

and in the **Now create this entry** section:

```
--setattr "userpassword='{CRYPT}$password1'"
```

Here's what gets logged when debug is turned on:

```
[Tue Feb 02 22:08:52.541857 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16097:tid 16365] [remote x.x.x.x:59726] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_session] admin@OURDOMAIN.EDU: user_add/1('john', givenname='John', sn='Smith', homedirectory='/home/smith', gecos="'John Smith'", loginshell='/bin/tcsh', uidnumber=5319, gidnumber=150, setattr=("userpassword='{CRYPT}the-actual-hash-of-the-password'",), version='2.239'): SUCCESS
```

So does that appear that `{CRYPT}` is not being interpreted? I also added some debug:

```
echo "Password hash value is $password1"
```

And what prints is the original hash, sans `{CRYPT}`.

So to test this outside of the script I added a test user:

```
ipa user-add --first=test --last=user --setattr userpassword='{CRYPT} the-actual-hash-of-the-password' testuser
```

Then I ran the following and the password worked:

```
ldapsearch -x -D 'uid=testuser,cn=users,cn=accountsdc=ourdomain,dc=edu' -W

# testuser, users, accounts, ourdomain.edu
dn: uid=testuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=ourdomain,dc=edu
givenName: test
sn: user
uid: testuser
cn: test user
displayName: test user
initials: tu
gecos: test user
krbPrincipalName: testuser@OURDOMAIN.EDU
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalperson
objectClass: inetorgperson
objectClass: inetuser
objectClass: posixaccount
objectClass: krbprincipalaux
objectClass: krbticketpolicyaux
objectClass: ipaobject
objectClass: ipasshuser
objectClass: fasuser
objectClass: ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
objectClass: mepOriginEntry
loginShell: /bin/sh
homeDirectory: /home/testuser
mail: testuser@ourdomain.edu
krbCanonicalName: testuser@OURDOMAIN.EDU
ipaUniqueID: 34ee1f48-65d2-11eb-8c33-001ec9ab7ef0
uidNumber: 1520800007
gidNumber: 1520800007
memberOf: cn=ipausers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=ourdomain,dc=edu
krbLastPwdChange: 20210203034524Z
krbPasswordExpiration: 20210504034524Z

# testuser, groups, accounts, ourdomain.edu
dn: cn=testuser,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=ourdomain,dc=edu
objectClass: posixgroup
objectClass: ipaobject
objectClass: mepManagedEntry
objectClass: top
cn: testuser
gidNumber: 1520800007
description: User private group for testuser
mepManagedBy: uid=testuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=ourdomain,dc
 =edu
ipaUniqueID: 34f39b4e-65d2-11eb-8c33-001ec9ab7ef0

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

Is it still possible to do this in the current versions?

Comment: Oh, the horror... A number of posts in this site would have a thing or three to say about that script. Shellcheck(.net) also does. (That's what I get for reading this site too much. Seeing what things look like in the real world would be much more painless if it didn't know too much.)

Comment: That first pair of seds and awks drops the middle letter "Q." from Jane Users name, is that the desired action or may it be preserved? (or should it be preserved, even?)

Comment: Preserved ideally, if not it's ok it it gets dropped. Thanks for the shellcheck.net suggestion, I can't reference the `/etc/passwd` file there.

Answer (score 0):

2 fixes:

```
--setattr "userpassword={CRYPT}$password1" --gidnumber=$gid
```

Also surround the echo command with double quotes at the top of the script where username is set:

```
username="$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d:)"
```

So the final script should be this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $1 is the NIS domain, $2 is the NIS master server
ypcat -d $1 -h $2 passwd > /dev/shm/nis-map.passwd 2>&1

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat /dev/shm/nis-map.passwd) ; do
    IFS=' '
    username="$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d:)"
    # Not collecting encrypted password because we need cleartext password
    # to create kerberos key
    uid=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d:)
    gid=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d:)
    gecos=$(echo $line | cut -f5 -d:)
    homedir=$(echo $line | cut -f6 -d:)
    shell=$(echo $line | cut -f7 -d:)

    # Now create this entry
    echo passw0rd1 | ipa user-add $username --first=NIS --last=USER \
         --password --gidnumber=$gid --uid=$uid --gecos='$gecos' --homedir=$homedir \
         --shell=$shell
    ipa user-show $username
done
```

And to deal with entries with a middle initial or lastname, firstname you can use this:

```
# Change Last, First to First Last. (Fill in dummy for empty gecos.)
if [ -z "$gecos" ]; then
firstlast='First Last'
else
firstlast=$(echo $gecos | sed -e 's/\(.*\), \(.*$\)/\2 \1/')
fi

# Extract First and Last into separate variables
first=$(echo $firstlast | awk '/^(\w|[-'\''])+ \w\. / { print $1,
$2; } \
/^(\w|[-'\''])+ (\w|[-'\''])+(
|$)/ {
print $1; }' )
#echo this dollar 1 $1 this is dollar 2 $2
last=$(echo $firstlast | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" ";} \
/^(\w|[-'\''])+ \w\. / { for (i=3;
i<=NF; i++) print $i; } \
/^(\w|[-'\''])+ (\w|[-'\''])+(
|$)/ {
for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i; }' \
| sed 's/ *$//' )
```